# Get size of each folder inside a function

Tags: powershell

I am trying to obtain the size of each folder and its sub-folders along with the owner, path, and last modified date - also up to a depth of 5. I have everything except for the size of the folder completed I am trying to get the size in MB. 
I am using PowerShell 4.
The structure I am trying to obtain:

```
 The structure I am trying to obtain:

 Date Modified Owner FullName                                            Size                                                                                                     
 ------------- ----- --------                                            ------                                                                
06/26/2017          /Users/demo/main/1slevel                             12.0MB
06/26/2017          /Users/demo/main/1slevel/2nlvel                       8.0MB
06/26/2017          /Users/demo/main/1slevel/2nlvel/3rdlvel               5.0MB
06/26/2017          /Users/demo/main/1slevel/2nlvel/3rdlvel/4thlev
06/26/2017          /Users/demo/main/1slevel/2nlvel/3rdlvel/4thlev/5thlevl
06/26/2017          /Users/demo/main/uns
06/26/2017          /Users/demo/main/uns/swan
06/26/2017          /Users/demo/main/uns/swan/drins
06/26/2017          /Users/demo/main/uns/swan/drins/furth
06/26/2017          /Users/demo/main/uns/swan/drins/furth/firf
```

The Code I have thus far:

```
Function Get-Depth {
   Param(
        [String]$Path = '/Users/demo/main',
        [String]$Filter = "*",
        [Int]$ToDepth = 4,
        [Int]$CurrentDepth = 0
    )
    #incrimintation
    $CurrentDepth++

  #obtains the path and passes the filter values. KEEP in mind that level 1 is 0.
     Get-ChildItem $Path | %{
     $_ | ?{ $_.Name -Like $Filter }
     #if thier is a folder, use the depth and run function until to depth value is 4
     If ($_.PsIsContainer) {
     If ($CurrentDepth -le $ToDepth) {

       # Call to function
       #adds the filter values and depth to the path..
       Get-Depth -Path $_.FullName -Filter $Filter `
        -ToDepth $ToDepth -CurrentDepth $CurrentDepth
           }
         }
      }

  }


#just calling the function and and adding what we want!

Get-Depth|? {$_.PsIsContainer}| select @{Name='Date Modified'; 
Expression={$_.LastWriteTime.ToString('MM/dd/yyyy')}},
@{Name='Owner'; E={(($_.GetAccessControl().Owner.Split('\'))[1])}}, Fullname
```

Thank you advance!

Comment: This should get you started: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730945.aspx

Comment: @CoryKnutson thank you cory, I've already looked into this. Is the only way to obtain the size of a folder is through going through the lengths of each file? thanks!

Comment: [Getting Directory Sizes in PowerShell](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2012/05/25/getting-directory-sizes-in-powershell/)

Comment: @ruslive109, Yes. That or making a reference outside of powershell like .NET or VB. There is an example of that at the bottom of the link I posted. 
`$objFSO = New-Object -com  Scripting.FileSystemObject` followed by `($objFSO.GetFolder("C:\Scripts").Size)`